# jsp. enum comparison / equality

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have following jsp fragment:

```
                       <td class="">${campaign.moderated}
                            <c:if test="${campaign.moderated} == TRUE">
                                <a href="#">click me</a>
                            </c:if>
                        </td>
```

Campaign class:

```
public class Campaign {
      //...
      private ModerationStatus moderated;
      //get and set
}
```

ModerationStatus :

```
public enum ModerationStatus {
    TRUE,
    FALSE,
    IN_PROGRESS
}
```

I cannot achieve the situation when `a` tag will render on jsp.

what Do I wrong?

P.S.

This table cell looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this works:

```
                          <c:if test="${campaign.moderated eq 'TRUE'}">
                                <a href="#">click me</a>
                            </c:if>
```

Answer (score -3):

Enum is represented in JSP as string. Change your code

```
<c:if test="${campaign.moderated} == TRUE">
```

To this

```
 <c:if test="${campaign.moderated} == 'TRUE'}">
```

So the full code is

```
  <td class="">${campaign.moderated}
                        <c:if test="${campaign.moderated} == 'TRUE'}">
                            <a href="#">click me</a>
                        </c:if>
                    </td>
```

EDIT
You did not closed bracket after *test* in *if*. I updated code above

Comment: As you can see this value render on the page

Comment: Sorry i did not noticed it. Problem is with bracket. I updated my answer